# How to find the id of the user whom I report to?

Tags: role-hierarchy, roles

I have functionality to implement, that involves two typse of users: Operators & Managers(defined in hierarchy by roles). The requisite, claims to add two buttons in a page, that should be visible to only one of the users, at a time.

For the operators, the button should redirect to a page, to "submit" some records for approvement, by the manager whom they directly respond in hierarchy.

In the other hand the managers, should be able to approve only records submitted by their subordinates.

What I need is to find the id of the *manager*, of the operator, to store it to the record which is going to be send for approval.

Please, any clue regarding this?

Thanks!
E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User object has "Manager" field, you can use this field but make sure all users manager information is updated in this field. It is lookup to User itself.

For more information: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=user_fields.htm&language=en_US